# Can I import *.d.ts instead of require it?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have some module `lib` in `node_modules` and I want to use it.
I wrote `lib.d.ts` for this.

Files looks like:

```
/src/
    main.ts (imports `lib`)
/types/
    lib.d.ts
```

In file `main.ts` I can write this code:

```
/// <reference path="../types/lib.d.ts" />
import {some} from 'lib';
```

And it works.

But when I try to use import for ambient declaration file:

```
import '../types/lib';
import {some} from 'lib';
```

it compiles without errors, but in resulting JS I can find require for this file:

```
require('../types/lib');
const lib_1 = require('lib');
```

With error in runtime of missing file `../types/lib` –
it's just an ambient declaration file without resulting file.

Why compiler did not remove import of *.d.ts file?
Can I use import somehow, or I must use reference instead?

**Solution:**

If you don't want to use `reference` directives,
you can just add required *.d.ts to files,
included by your tsconfig.json.

My tsconfig.json was:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es2015",
        "lib": ["es2016"],
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "newLine": "LF",
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "sourceMap": false,
        "outDir": "../build",
        "types": [
            "node"
        ]
    },
    "files": [
        "index.ts"
    ]
}
```

Early I tried to add my .d.ts to `types` section, but in this case
tcs is trying to find this file in node_modules/@types directory.

After suggestion I tried to add file in `files` section:

```
    "files": [
        "index.ts",
        "types/lib.d.ts"
    ]
```

It's works and seems as a good solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't have to `import` an ambient definition file.

You can manually `/// <reference` it. But the right way is just to make it available for the compiler through the file `tsconfig.json`.

An example of `tsconfig.json` that includes anything but `node_modules`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

The [documentation on `tsconfig.json` is here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html).

Comment: Thanks for suggestion!

I prefer to use `files` instead of `exclude`, but you give me the right direction.

I updated my question, adding this solution.

Comment: No help for me i got err: Cannot find module './img/logo_game_0.png'.

Comment: How do I make sure that it's actually found the `d.ts` file? I should be getting errors from using functions in the JS library that I did not `declare` in the `d.ts` file, but I'm not...