# Can I import dom types explicitly?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Conventionally, developers would include global dom types globally and use them globally.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
      "dom"
    ]
  },
}
```

Is it possible to use dom types explicitly?

Something like:

```
import { MessagePort, HTMLElement } from 'dom'
```

Answer (score 7):

You may not `import` from `lib.dom.d.ts`; it is not a module, and provides declarations that should be available in the global namespace. However, you can avoid the need for changes to tsconfig.json by adding a reference to the library you want from the files that use it.

To express a reference to DOM libraries from within Typescript files, you can use [Triple Slash Directives](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html#-reference-lib-)—specifically, `lib="dom"`, which defines [HTMLElement](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/48fa3a5f18a7090a7b3fb8836159fee7e48a8013/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L6693) and [MessagePort](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/48fa3a5f18a7090a7b3fb8836159fee7e48a8013/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L10682).

As documented, this must occur *at the top of your file* (with the exception of other comments):

```js
/// <reference lib="dom" />
```

**See also:** [Can I import *.d.ts instead of require it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40949693/1426891)

Comment: But [Using /// <reference lib="dom" /> in a .d.ts typescript declaration file has global effects](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33901); so your entire project will end up with the lib.dom values in global scope.

Comment: @RobertTupelo-Schneck Yes; that's by design. Typescript assumes that if you're running in an execution environment that needs and uses those definitions, you should include them all. I can see why you might want specific interfaces or definitions instead of everything, but to the best of my understanding Typescript doesn't support that, and if it ever does I'd happily upvote that answer over mine. In the meantime, Ryan has recommended [separate tsconfig files](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39100#issuecomment-645458394) in an issue duped against the one you linked.