# Reference TypeScript dom lib types locally

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-lib-dom

Several types from TypeScript built-in DOM lib needs to be used in local module for cross-platform code piece, e.g.:

```
// foo.ts
export let foo: EventListener = (e) => ...;
```

This can be achieved by adding:

```
/// <reference lib="dom" />
```

The problem is that other modules in this project become polluted with DOM-related types, while they aren't specific to browser or DOM.

```
// bar.ts
class Animation {
    ...
}
```

This results in name collision errors for any variables that may have the same names as browser globals, e.g.:

> Duplicate identifier '...'.ts(2300)
>
> lib.dom.d.ts: '...' was also declared here.

> Definitions of the following identifiers conflict with those in another file: ...  ts(6200)
>
> lib.dom.d.ts: Conflicts are in this file.

> Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable '...'.ts(2451)
>
> lib.dom.d.ts: '...' was also declared here.

I would prefer to avoid pasting a hierarchy of types like `EventListener` from lib.dom.d.ts if possible.

How can types from built-in libs be used in one local module without affecting other modules?

Comment: I have the same problem. Really want to have a way to import runtime types with normal module semantics, eg. `import * as dom from "dom"`.

Comment: See [Why am I still getting types from lib.dom.d.ts when I have overridden the lib property in my tsconfig to omit the dom lib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63109147/why-am-i-still-getting-types-from-lib-dom-d-ts-when-i-have-overridden-the-lib-property)

Comment: @xiaoyi See [this issue on *@types/web*](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-DOM-lib-generator/issues/1207)

Answer (score 4):

As answered [here on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59061266/can-i-import-dom-types-explicitly#comment111913480_59061859) and on [TypeScript's GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39100#issuecomment-645458394), this is not possible within a single TypeScript project and this is by design.

But so as a workaround, you can make separate TypeScript projects for the modules that should have access to `dom` types and for the modules that don't.